# Testing Application with Monkey

Tags: android, adb, monkey

I'm trying to use Monkey to test the UI of my application but have so far been unsuccessful. I've connected my device to my computer and attempted to run monkey using adb.

The command I'm using is:

```
 adb shell monkey -p com.cooper.redditvideo -v 500
```

And the error message is:

```
:Monkey: seed=1392819534260 count=500
:AllowPackage: com.cooper.redditvideo
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.MONKEY
```

Now from what I can tell its trying to say that it can't find an activity with the above two categories to be able to run, however I have specified this in my manifest.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cooper.redditvideo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.cooper.redditvideo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <catagory android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.cooper.redditvideo.AboutActivity"
            android:label="About"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your app installed on your device?  What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: Yes the app it's installed on my device, is my primary development platform. The error is that monkey won't run due to not being able to find an activity with the LAUNCHER and MONKEY categories.

Comment: Try `adb shell monkey -p com.cooper.redditvideo -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -c android.intent.category.MONKEY -v 500`

Comment: You need to post the actual error.

Comment: @shoerat I tried that and got pretty much the same results, it seems I can type any package name and it will display that.

Comment: @GLee I've edited my post to highlight what the error message is.